# angular 9 using dynamic meta information for social share but not using SSR

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, socialshare

I have an angular 9 app and i was applying the dynamic meta tags and come across that in order to get the respective image and description of the page we need to apply the server side rendering. but when i came across the server side rendering , it is a very big task and the system is already in the production environment and this social share is not a very big task

So is there any other quicker way than the server side rendering so that the dynamic meta can be applied successfully and run on social pages ?